# Using AWS LocalCreds (~/.aws) with hardened systemd file, possible?

Tags: debian, systemd, aws, systemd-unit

As you may be aware, AWS SDKs provide for reading credentials from `~/.aws/credentials` and config from `~/.aws/config`.

However I am unclear as to how (if ?) I can use this facility in conjunction with a locked-down systemd `service` file.  My file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=foobar
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
[Service]
# RUN
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/path_to_my_binary
ExecReload=/usr/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/usr/bin/kill -QUIT $MAINPID
Restart=on-failure
# ENV
Environment="FOO=bar"
Environment="BAR=foo"
# SECURITY
CapabilityBoundingSet=
DynamicUser=yes
LockPersonality=yes
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=yes
NoNewPrivileges=yes
PrivateDevices=yes
PrivateTmp=yes
PrivateUsers=yes
ProcSubset=pid
ProtectClock=yes
ProtectControlGroups=yes
ProtectHome=yes
ProtectHostname=yes
ProtectKernelLogs=yes
ProtectKernelModules=yes
ProtectKernelTunables=yes
ProtectProc=invisible
ProtectSystem=strict
RemoveIPC=yes
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_INET AF_INET6 AF_UNIX
RestrictNamespaces=yes
RestrictRealtime=yes
SystemCallArchitectures=native
SystemCallFilter=~@cpu-emulation @debug @mount @obsolete @privileged @raw-io @reboot @swap
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```